# Qualitative Argument in a Projectile Motion Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image: Question on Projectile Motion]

Essentially, my qualms are with Part (a). The argument I’ve come up with are as follows:

The ball was launched perpendicular to the plane. That means that the launch angle, which is the angle with respect to the horizontal, is 90-θ. Since the path of a projectile is parabolic, with its trajectory being determined by a quadratic polynomial, it must also be continuous. This is because of the continuity of a quadratic polynomial. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, this means that there is a value of θ such that the height of point P is the same as the initial height. That proves the existence of θ.

Now, the explanation given in the answers is quite different and I do understand it. I was just wondering if my proposed argument above works or not. I would be appreciative if someone could help me on this.

Comment: The trajectory is a quadratic for $y$ in terms of $x$ not $\theta$.

Comment: That is true. I did not say that it is quadratic in theta. I simply stated that it has polynomial continuity. Since x is a continuous function of theta, we know that y must also be a continuous function of theta (I did not state this explicitly). I, then, skipped the second step that tfb reminded me of and proceeded directly to the third step. That's where my mistake was. 

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your answer works: you are correct to use the intermediate value theorem, but what you need to show is: if $P_y$ is the height of $P$, and $L_y$ is the height at which the ball is launched, then

1. $P_y(\theta)$ & $L_y(\theta)$ are continuous functions of $\theta$;
2. There are values of $\theta$ such that $P_y(\theta) - L_y(\theta) < 0$ and also $P_y(\theta) - L_y(\theta) > 0$;
3. Hence by the intermediate value theorem there is a value of $\theta$ such that $P_y(\theta) - L_y(\theta) = 0$.

You have not done the second step (and the first step could be clearer I think).

Comment: Oh, your argument is exactly the same as the one given in the book. I get why my argument was not correct. Thanks!